# Keeping/saving view state using a navigationview when switching from one tab to another

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I have a ContentView quite simple with a toolbar enabling selection among some more complex secondary views:

```swift
   enum SelectedTab {
        case checklist
        case altitude
    }
    
    @State var selectedTab: SelectedTab?
    
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                switch selectedTab {
                    case .checklist:
                        ChecklistView()
                    case .altitude:
                        AltitudeView()
                    default:
                    ChecklistView()
                }                
            }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that when I switch from one tab to another, the view is replaced and all content resets: How can I save the view state when switching from one tab to another, including scroll position in lists, toggle, fields?

Thanks

Comment: You have to create an appropriate (persistent) view model for each view which maintains the states.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about how to do that? Sorry for my ignorance